# SwiftUI: Can you have a different background color for the top and bottom of a ScrollView?

Tags: swift, swiftui, background, scrollview

Is it possible to have different background color for the top and bottom of a ScrollView?

For example, I when I scroll upwards, I'd like the green background of the ScrollView to be blue, and when I scroll downwards I'd like the green background of the ScrollView to be red:

[image]

Comment: I dpa't understand what you are aiming for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, replace your background with this:

```
.background(VStack(spacing: .zero) { Color.blue; Color.red })
```

Answer (score 7):

Previous answer is OK, but when you drag the scroll down you may see the bottom color and vice verse. To create expected behaviour I dynamically resize background views based on current scroll offset.

```
struct DoubleSidedBackgroundScrollView<Content: View>: View {

    private let ContentBuilder: () -> Content
    private let topColor: Color
    private let bottomColor: Color
    
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = .zero
    
    init(topColor: Color, bottomColor: Color, contentBuilder: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.ContentBuilder = contentBuilder
        self.topColor = topColor
        self.bottomColor = bottomColor
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                ContentBuilder()
            
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    let offset = proxy.frame(in: .named("scroll")).minY
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ScrollViewOffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: offset)
                }
            }
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
        .onPreferenceChange(ScrollViewOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
            offset = value
        }
        .background(
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                topColor
                    .frame(
                        height: max(offset + (UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2), 0),
                        alignment: .top)
                bottomColor
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        )
    }
}

private struct ScrollViewOffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = .zero

    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJaLd.gif)

Comment: This worked so much better then the accepted answer for me.